# Emscripten "incoming" installation unusually big

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, emscripten

I installed Emscripten on an Ubuntu 14.04 Docker container using the emsdk as so:

```
emsdk install emscripten-incoming
emsdk install clang-incoming-64bit
```

Installation finishes successfully and everything is working fine, although I later noticed that the Docker image takes about 12 GB of my hard disk.
When I was using the master branch of Emscripten it only weighed around 2GB.
This is causing me problems while I'm uploading the image to my server.
Is there anything I can do about the installation's large size?

EDIT:
Here is the Dockerfile I used:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

RUN apt-get install -y cmake
RUN apt-get install -y ninja-build
RUN apt-get install -y python2.7
RUN apt-get install -y default-jre
RUN apt-get install -y git
RUN apt-get install -y python
RUN apt-get install -y g++
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs-legacy

# Download emsdk
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN cd /tmp && curl 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/mozilla-games/emscripten/releases/emsdk-portable.tar.gz' | tar xvz

# Install emsdk
RUN /tmp/emsdk_portable/emsdk update
RUN /tmp/emsdk_portable/emsdk install emscripten-incoming
RUN /tmp/emsdk_portable/emsdk install clang-incoming-64bit
RUN /tmp/emsdk_portable/emsdk activate emscripten-incoming

ENV PATH /tmp/emsdk_portable:$PATH
ENV PATH /tmp/emsdk_portable/clang/fastcomp/build_master_64/bin:$PATH
ENV PATH /tmp/emsdk_portable/emscripten/incoming:$PATH

ENV EMSCRIPTEN /tmp/emsdk_portable/emscripten/incoming

RUN apt-get install -y python-yaml
```

EDIT:
Here is the previous Dockerfile using the master branch of Emscripten.
The only difference is the Emscripten branch (and that I moved the installation to /usr/local/emscripten).
I just built this image and it weighs around 2GB.

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

RUN apt-get install -y cmake
RUN apt-get install -y ninja-build
RUN apt-get install -y python2.7
RUN apt-get install -y default-jre
RUN apt-get install -y git
RUN apt-get install -y python
RUN apt-get install -y g++
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs-legacy

# Download emsdk
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/emscripten
RUN cd /usr/local/emscripten && curl 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/mozilla-games/emscripten/releases/emsdk-portable.tar.gz' | tar xvz

# Install emsdk
RUN /usr/local/emscripten/emsdk_portable/emsdk update
RUN /usr/local/emscripten/emsdk_portable/emsdk install emscripten-master
RUN /usr/local/emscripten/emsdk_portable/emsdk install clang-master-64bit
RUN /usr/local/emscripten/emsdk_portable/emsdk activate emscripten-master

ENV PATH /usr/local/emscripten/emsdk_portable:$PATH
ENV PATH /usr/local/emscripten/emsdk_portable/clang/fastcomp/build_master_64/bin:$PATH
ENV PATH /usr/local/emscripten/emsdk_portable/emscripten/master:$PATH

ENV EMSCRIPTEN /usr/local/emscripten/emsdk_portable/emscripten/master

RUN apt-get install -y python-yaml
```

Comment: Are you measuring the size of the image, or the image and every single intermediate container?

Comment: I'm measuring the virtual size of the image as indicated by "docker images". I measured the master branch of Emscripten exactly the same way and it was only 2GB.

Comment: Without testing it, from memory, `emscripten-incoming` contains the full git log and .git folder. This may explain the comparatively larger size.

Comment: How did you build your image, with a `docker commit` or with a Dockerfile and a `docker build -t mytag .` ?

Comment: I used a Dockerfile. I just added the Dockerfile to the question.

Comment: Was your dockerfile in your home directory (with a lot of files) or alone in a specific directory ?

Comment: @TalZion, did you find any answer to this issue?  I had the same problem some time back and am now revisiting compiling with Emscripten in Docker.

Comment: @bnieland Yes and no. I just stopped using the incoming branch..

Answer (score 2):

In terms of generally reducing the image size, there's lots you can do:

- Consider using a debian image instead of an ubuntu one, which should work for your purposes and is much smaller.
- Don't do `RUN apt-get upgrade -y`. Instead update your image by pulling the new version of the base image and rebuilding when you need to.
- Put all your `apt-get install` stuff on the same line and remove the unneeded files afterwards with `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/` e.g:

  ```
  RUN apt-get update \
      && apt-get install -y cmake \
                      ninja-build \
      ...
      && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
  ```
- Get rid of any unneeded dependencies or use smaller versions; do you really need full g++ and two versions of python?
- See if you can build emscripten in one container, then copy the binaries into a new container. That way you can ditch the build dependencies. Alternately, you could install the build dependencies, build emscripten and remove the dependencies all in the same `RUN` instruction. This gets a bit messy, but I notice [this emscripten Dockerfile](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/cmfatih/emscripten/dockerfile/) does it.

I can't help in terms of reducing the size of emscripten in particular though.

Comment: Why is it not a good idea to upgrade an image? My rationale was that I want all the new packages and security fixes installed.
I separate the apt-get install lines so that if I change one of them in the future, docker will be able to use the cache and it won't have to reinstall all of the packages.
I didn't notice I'm installing both python2.7 and python, but it seems the python package depends on python2.7 so it's not installing two versions of Python.
I'll try to do what you suggested to reduce the size of the image, but from my testing it seems that the Emscripten branch is the main problem

Comment: It's just that the correct way is to pull a new version of the ubuntu image, which should be up to date. If it's not, complain. If you need a specific package, pull it yourself. Otherwise your slowing down the Docker build considerably for everyone and probably installing a lot of stuff you don't need. I took out DO NOT as it was a bit strong :). You might want to refer to the python images as to how to install python (they just do it from source IIRC).